# etc/init.d/bind9: No such or directory

Tags: dns, ip, bind

I can't find the bind9 file in the init.d directory
I have installed bind9 many times, and nothing happens
[etc/init.d/bind9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO1kn.png)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Isn't the command `sudo systemctl start named` and then check with `sudo systemctl status named`?

Comment: i use ubuntu 22

Comment: thank u so much, my problem SOLVED love uuu, sry IM new in ubuntu :)